# MySQL:Selecting items that have one atribute when last modified but did not have some other atrubute in the past

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a table titles that is structured in the folowing way

```
emp_no  title               from_date   to_date
109006  Senior Engineer     1998-02-10  9999-01-01
109008  Senior Engineer     1998-09-23  9999-01-01
109009  Senior Engineer     1998-10-21  9999-01-01
109010  Assistant Engineer  1986-05-23  1994-05-23
109010  Senior Engineer     2002-05-23  9999-01-01
109012  Senior Engineer     1995-08-31  2000-04-30
109014  Senior Engineer     1986-09-04  9999-01-01
109015  Senior Engineer     1996-10-15  9999-01-01
109017  Assistant Engineer  1997-06-22  9999-01-01
109018  Assistant Engineer  1988-08-15  1996-08-15
```

I want to select those who are Senior Engineers but not those who are Assistant Engineers . The one with `emp_no 109010` for example should not be shown.

I tried this

```
select * from titles where title='Senior Engineer' AND title NOT IN (select emp_no from titles where title='Assistant Engineer')
```

but it does not work.

Comment: *but it does work* considering it does **not** work.. Do you have any `NULL` values in `emp_no` ?

Comment: No . There aren't any NULL values. The answer from Alex below seems to give me  the result I wanted.

Comment: @LeonidisDimitris, once checked - accept Alex's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are close:

```
select * from titles 
where title='Senior Engineer' and emp_no
NOT IN (select emp_no from titles where title='Assistant Engineer')
```

Comment: I prefer this `..and not exists (select 1 from titles t where t.emp_no = titles.emp_no and  t.title='Assistant Engineer')` Handles the `NULL` values if sub-query has it

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM titles t
WHERE 

  -- items that have one atribute when last modified 
  title='Senior Engineer' 
  AND
  NOT EXISTS(
   SELECT null FROM titles t1
      AND t1.emp_no = t.empno
      AND t1.from_date > t.from_date
  )
  AND

  -- but did not have some other atrubute in the past
  NOT EXISTS(
   SELECT null FROM titles t1
      AND t1.emp_no = t.empno
      AND t1.from_date < t.from_date
      AND (t1.title <>'Senior Engineer' OR t1.title IS NULL)
  )
```